# Detect first record of a select clause in Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

After making a select in a CONTENT object, is it possible to detect with a conditional (maybe an "if") if the actual record is the first on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## untested

```
10 = CONTENT
10. ....
10.renderObj = COA
10.renderObj.5 = TEXT
10.renderObj.5.value = <h1>first Object</h1>
10.renderObj.5.if.equals = 0
10.renderObj.5.if.value.data = {cObj:parentRecordNumber} 
10.renderObj.10 < tt_content
```